# Spring Access-Control-Allow-Origins is not returned in the responses

Tags: spring, http-headers, cors

I have a spring-boot-starter-webflux with spring-security application but when I send a request, the Access-Control-Allow-Origins header is not returned in the response.

This is the CORS config:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
class CorsConfig : WebFluxConfigurer {

  override fun addCorsMappings(corsRegistry: CorsRegistry) {
    corsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
      .allowedOrigins("*")
      .allowedHeaders("*")
      .allowedMethods("*")
      .maxAge(3600)
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
  fun corsFilter(): CorsWebFilter {

    val config = CorsConfiguration()
    config.allowCredentials = true
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*")
    config.addAllowedHeader("*")
    config.addAllowedMethod("*")
    val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config)
    return CorsWebFilter(source)
  }
}

@Component
class AddControlHeaderWebFilter : WebFilter {

  override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
    val headers = exchange.response.headers
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Header", "*")
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Method", "*")
    return chain.filter(exchange)
  }

}

@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain? {
    http
      .authorizeExchange()
      .pathMatchers("/**").permitAll()
      .anyExchange().authenticated()
      .and()
      .exceptionHandling()
      .accessDeniedHandler(HttpStatusServerAccessDeniedHandler(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN))
      .and()
      .oauth2ResourceServer()
      .jwt()
      .jwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor())
    http.cors()
    http.csrf().disable()
    return http.build()
  }
}
```

**Request headers**

```
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJvQTRLYVJjWVJuMDFLWlhCSll4djBvT1JYNnZxbm5OOUszRnFEdEQtM0tnIn0.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.LyaZvyAxaa201D4vE9JLGCCJS4s_JXc-iRpegNngcZ9H9uIFQKeFkyl5jm12u-gN9lR7sQ8Qqp7W-g1m-2zc5Te3XQIbv2Al5-FW8w_zctWWthfTwwdxMFGcjbG_DCJvXaJlkwcaxK0ah0207yJo9fKZoL5jbBQdbopf0V2Pl7tsJDawwk1D92Mf1aaxTmjqUetltsrY_OU3zH4Ln9i6DxTuYlDB0K2vyr5jX9sjTZowXypVHeIwhbR4s0B368nmpxkaoSfxa-iMTTJ-nqEAJL0H2FPUHBbeaNR5Oaei62zeysbb-cU_f45OKOuGWFvZBWvtcI1N8MMOo9w-8-dwYQ
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.2
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 485c16ca-aaf2-482e-a4f7-47b603684719
Host: localhost:8200
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: SESSION=1a0b99b2-44d5-4224-86ea-510d5c6d5603
```

**Response headers**

```
transfer-encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Set-Cookie: SESSION=; Path=/; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
```

Why "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" are not returned in the response? My browser is blocking the preflight requests and I guess is because this header is not in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the @Bean declaration from CorsConfig to the Application class and it works like a charm.

```kotlin
@EnableWebFlux
class TrainingServiceApplication {

  @Bean
  fun corsConfigurationSource(): CorsConfigurationSource {
    val configuration = CorsConfiguration()
    configuration.allowedOrigins = listOf("*")
    configuration.allowedMethods = listOf("*")
    configuration.allowedHeaders = listOf("*")
    val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration)
    return source
  }

}
```

**Response headers**

```
transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
```

I do not understand why if the bean is declared in a separate file with @Configuration notation does not work but this other way it works.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if CorsWebFilter is register by default with http.cors() you may need to add as a filter. In the documentation, you should use CorsConfigurationSource (sorry java version):

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```